# Ruby OOP correct concept?

Tags: ruby, oop

The exercise questions are below with my answers.

```
#Create a Tree class with a rings attribute and getter method.
#Trees create a ring for every winter that passes
#It should have a bear_fruit? method which should return true if the
#has fruit that year. the tree produces fruit when it has
#more than 7 rings but less than 15, but false otherwise.
#The class should also have an winter_season method that increases #rings attr by 1.
```

Can anyone give me constructive criticism on this code?

```
class Tree

  attr_accessor :winters, :rings, :bear_fruit?

  def initialize(winters, rings)
    @winters = winters
    @rings = rings   
  end

  def rings_created
    @winters = 0
    @rings = 0
    while @winters == @rings do
      @winters +=1
      @rings +=1
      break if @winters == 100  
    end 
  end
  end

  def bear_fruit
    if @rings > 6 || < 16
      @bear_fruit? = true
    else 
      @bear_fruit? = false   
    end
  end

 def winter_season
   @winters = 0
   @rings = 0
   while @winters < @rings do
     @winters +=1
     @rings +=2
     break if @winters == 100   
   end  
   end 
 end

end
```

Comment: typo, it is 2am where i am..

Comment: You can't make instance variables like `@bear_fruit?`. They cannot have `?` in them like method names can. Your indentation here is all over the place as well. It's important to have well-organized, orderly code in order to see clearly what's happening and identify mistakes. Remember the best way to crack these problems is to develop simple unit tests that express what your code is supposed to do, then go back and make the code work properly. This is the principle of [test driven development](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development) or TDD.

Comment: Please make an effort to format your code properly. It might be 2am for other readers as well ;)

Comment: @margo was just about to fix but you beat me to the punch. I promise it looked better before pasting ;)

Comment: You should have fixed it before submitting, that's what the preview is for. Right away, from the formatting anyone can see that this wont work as is. The most important thing with programming is to make it work, then worry about improving it. This may seem harsh, but you will get alot more help if you show that you've made a proper effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the exercise, you are supposed to create a class `Tree` with a single attribute `rings` and two methods, `bear_fruit?` and `winter_season`:

> - Create a `Tree` class with
>
>   - a `rings` attribute and getter method
>   - a `bear_fruit?` method which
>
>     - returns `true` if the tree has more than 7 rings but less than 15
>     - returns `false` otherwise
>   - a `winter_season` method that
>
>     - increases `rings` by 1

That's all. It doesn't say that a tree should track winters and it doesn't mention any loops.

Here's how I would implement it:

```
class Tree
  attr_reader :rings

  def initialize
    @rings = 0
  end

  def bear_fruit?
    @rings > 7 && @rings < 15
  end

  def winter_season
    @rings += 1
  end
end
```

Comment: `(8..14).include?(@rings)`  is a little more Rubyish and English.

Comment: @KeithBennett you could also write `@rings.between?(8, 14)`, but that leads to different numbers in code and specification. `@rings > 7 && @rings < 15` resembles *"more than 7 but less than 15"* more closely, IMO.

Comment: What you say is true, but I would argue that there is value in deviating from the literal specification to use a notation that is more human-natural. (And, though the numbers differ, the conditions are identical.)  I think the fact that we think in > && < terms is an artifact of our having to program in relatively lower level languages like C, C++, and Java, and that changing this style, despite its modest cognitive cost in the short term, is worthwhile.

Comment: @KeithBennett natural language is often a bit ambiguous. Without referring to the documentation, it's unclear if `between?` is inclusive or exclusive. A `<` on the other hand is precise in that regard. A chained notation like `7 < @rings < 15` would be perfect, but unfortunately, Ruby - unlike Python - doesn't support such syntax.

Comment: I get that you value precision, and I can appreciate that. My suggestion was not `between` but rather `(8..14).include?(@rings)`.  Assuming one knows the bounds of a range in Ruby (which as I'm sure you know is inclusive of the lower bound and inclusive of the upper bound with 2 dots, and exclusive with 3), there is nothing ambiguous about it. And while this one expression in isolation may not be significant, the accumulation of many such lower level constructs IMO incurs a higher cognitive cost in understanding a page of code. I do like that Python notation, very mathematical.

Comment: thanks @Stefan - did you choose to not include an if and else statement in bear_fruit? because the method will return false regardless of if it being defined?

Comment: @whatabout11 `bear_fruit?` will return whatever `>` and `<` return, i.e. a boolean value (you can try that yourself: open IRB and type `1 < 2`). Adding `if` and `else` is therefore redundant, basically like writing `if true then true; else false`.

Answer (score 1):

First, does it work? I'm guessing not. Run it and see what the error is.

Ruby provides a number of ways of looping which you can look up in the [ruby docs](http://ruby-doc.org/). I prefer not to use while loops if I can avoid it, partly because it can lead to less readable code with the use of break. Look up the times method and other enumerables.